# How do I disable VS PowerTools tooltips?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

[image: Very annoying]

I have to click two times, each time I want to read the doc. I have found that this increases my development time incredibly.

Unfortunately the Visual Studio team doesn't seem to notice or care about my request/questions, that's why I ask here. Any way to configure this so it shows all the text by default or replace it with the old tooltip system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uncheck:

Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Solution Navigator -> "Enable Interactive Tooltips"